# C# System.Configuration.Configuration Import/Export

Tags: c#

I use the System.Configuration.Configuration to save many user settings.
I want to allow the user to export some of the settings, and import them later
(or in other instance of the program).
However, I didn't find a way to do it (save a file that contains only a subset of the
configuration sections, and then load this sections to the system).

Is there a way in C# to import and export parts of the configuration?

Comment: The problem you're facing here is a great reason not to use System.Configuration for this purpose. System.Configuration should be limited to rarely changed settings that control the overall configuration of the system (hence its name) rather than often changing user settings. It's so easy to serialize your own preferences file to and from XML (or anything else) that there's no value in using System.Configuration for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Using the default behavior of Microsoft .NET application settings architecture, specific user data is stored in a file named user.config, stored under the user's home directory. This is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.localfilesettingsprovider.aspx).

For exporting the entire user settings collection you would just need to store the contents of that file. In order to export only some of the settings you can always read only the desired settings, i guess.

This article may also be useful, [Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh%28VS.80%29.aspx).